# Oracle Procedure Calling using Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, stored-procedures

I am New to Spring jdbcTemplate
I have a oracle procedure which is already compiled in oracle database that is

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC(days_to_arch IN number DEFAULT 1)
IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('START - TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC ');
  dbms_output.put_line('Archieving for last '|| days_to_arch || ' days and ' );
    INSERT
    INTO IP_CO_WR2_USR.TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_ARCH
    SELECT * 
    FROM IP_CO_WR2_USR.TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_TEMP
                where insert_timestamp < (CAST (trunc(sysdate-days_to_arch)  AS TIMESTAMP));
    DELETE 
    FROM IP_CO_WR2_USR.TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_TEMP
                where insert_timestamp < (CAST (trunc(sysdate-days_to_arch)  AS TIMESTAMP));
    COMMIT  ; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('END - TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC ');
END;
```

I Want to execute this procedure using Spring JdbcTemplate, as you can see i don't want to return anything from this procedure! Please guide me!

i have tried 2 or 3 solution from the other sources but they didn't work without throwing any exception

1st way

```
SimpleJdbcCall procReadActor=new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC");
                SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("days_to_arch", 3);
                Map out = procReadActor.execute(in);
```

2nd way

```
jdbcTemplate.update("{call TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC (?)}", 3);
```

3rd way

```
  Connection connection = jndiDataSource.getConnection();
  connection.setAutoCommit(false);
  CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC(?)}");
  callableStatement.setInt(1, 3);
  System.out.println(callableStatement.executeUpdate());;
  connection.commit();
```

Please guide me to write this code!

Comment: What exception you encounter in each *way* you tried ?

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond - all execute without any exception but nothing effected on database

Comment: okies.  what do you see in the logs ? Try enabling the `DEBUG` level and analyse

Comment: No Nothing is shown in log, debug mode is on all 3 ways mentioned above just execute without effect the database other end if execute procedure manually using sqldeveloper its effect the database.

Comment: Are you sure you're not swallowing exceptions when you call the procedure?

Comment: @dsp_user- yes m sure about it.my code already in try catch and i am prining log trace but no exception is showing.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting with correct DB. Try to raise exception in stored procedure `Raise_Application_Error (-20000, 'xxxxxxxx.');`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz  yes its connecting with the correct one, after raising exception it shows
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource@6874b063
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate@3c44071d
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: xxxxxxxx.
ORA-06512: at "IP_CO_WR2_USR.TRANSFORM_TRN_AFEES_KVP_PROC", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)

Comment: That's mean procedure is executed correctly. And something wrong is with query  or you are passing null value as parameter. Add simple insert in your procedure to save days_to_arch  in DB. Or raise days_to_arch  with `Raise_Application_Error((-20000,'day_arch is' ||nvl(days_to_arch ,'null')`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz No i passed the same value as mentioned in my question using callable statement

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz i also tried it without parameter, i change the proc to no argument proc and hardcord the day_to_arch value but its still not effecting db.

Comment: Add simple insert in your procedure `insert into table(value) values('a');` Maybe you don't do  commit to in other sessions and jdbc session has empty tables.